# Will there be benefits to reviewers in the new peer review system?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>
> [New Community Review badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges)

This might be an interesting benefit for people like myself, who don't ask or answer much, but instead have an interest in learning.

Anyway, I've been a member of SO for a year and a half now and my rep is fairly low. I only code occasionally (with university and all) so I'm still a bit of a novice, and don't have much insight to offer to existing questions. Most questions I have myself are already answered.

I do lurk frequently and am very happy to see the new edit-review system rolling out. I understand most questions, even though I can't answer them. I've always wanted to be able to edit some for formatting or clarity. Now I can!

Anyway, there are some limits set on the editing. It has to be approved by either two people or a 20k user/mod(?). It seems a bit slow, especially for trivial edits like grammar, tags or formatting.

Could there be badges awarded to accurate review editors? Or (my personal feature-request), an edit-accuracy system which will allow frequent reviewers who have a high rate of edit acceptance to have the full editing powers of 3k users at a lower level?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit early to be discussing this, short answer is **we do not know**.

I totally support having a badge or 2 that relate to this feature.

I am strongly against unlocking full edit rights for users with less that 2k rep. This would heavily complicate things and not be obvious at all. All of our privileges have a reputation level.

We are probably going to allow you to level up to around 1k rep using edits only, it will be fairly slow at 2 rep a pop (we may require a percentage of answer/question rep and other caps), plans are to cap the benefit from edits to 1000 rep.

Comment: Having a "first peer reviewed edit" badge would create a problem: a first badge that is only possible with less reputation. Invitation for sock puppet accounts?