# New review - Are all of the counts restarted from scratch?

Tags: support, review

It has been quite a while since I last visited the review page. By now, the old review links are not there anymore and the new review system seems to be in use.

I would like to know, what will happen with the previous stats that I held? I remember I had actioned about 150 reviews (don't remember the number exactly). So, are all the previous counters/stat erased and won't they count now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only count that's been "backfilled" is the Suggested Edit count.

Apparently all the other counts were "too hard" to separate out from the old data.

Comment: Heh, forgot about suggested edits still counting. Shamelessly updated my own answer with that info. :-P

Answer (score 0):

You count up from now, mostly.

The old review badge has been replaced by [three new badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) that are easier to track based just on your review count. Stats for the old review system are not taken into account for these badges, except for your suggested edits review count.