# When bumped by bounty, modified timestamp should link to the bounty message

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bump, bounty-remarks

When a post gets bumped to the top of active tab due to a new bounty, the "modified" timestamp should link to the bounty message.

Background: [New Community Review badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) post was bumped to the top in active tab and it took a bit of research to find out what actually caused this bump. I was expecting that clicking on the [modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges/?lastactivity) link would show me what got updated. There were no new answers and no edits to question or existing answers. I checked the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/147912/timeline), didn't help. Since the edit timestamp of the question was not recent so checking [revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/147912/revisions) didn't cross my mind. By chance I saw the date on the bounty message and figured that adding bounty bumped the post.

So, I believe that clicking on "modified" link should somehow show the bounty message or bring it into the viewable area.

Comment: A [userscript of mine](http://stackapps.com/q/4134/) should help you in this case - you don't have to click the link to [find out what causes the bump](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yRpl2.png).

Comment: As bounty notices are now shown at the top of questions rather than below their comments at the time this was requested, I don't think this request is relevant anymore.

Comment: What *does* clicking the timestamp next to "modified" or "Active" currently link to? If I had to guess, it's a link to the question itself (rather than, for instance, the most recently edited answer). I don't think there's currently a way to link to a particular notice/banner above a post. And the fact that the bounty was added will be listed in the revision history for the post as well as in the post's timeline. So yeah, I don't see there being much of a need for this functionality to be added.

Comment: @V2Blast I've always thought it makes more sense for the "modified" link to lead to the revision history (at least for questions). This will work for bounties, reopens, as well as regular edits. And the user can always click "Return to Question". Or if they wanted to open the post view from the beginning, they could just click on the post title rather than the "modified" link. [1/2]

Comment: The only problem with this is that "modified" links to `?lastactivity`, not to a direct link. But I see no problem with adding this functionality to "Active" too so that the `?lastactivity` link always redirects to revisions (at least when the target post is a question). [2/2]